# Is it possible to scroll sticky block with page scrolling?

Tags: html, css, scroll, sticky

I have two `50%` width columns template - with `700% and 200%` of height. 200% column is sticky bottom, so I can always see it.

But if I scroll to the bottom of the page and start scroll up - right column will not be scrolling. It will start scrolling only when I get up to 200% of page top.

Is it possible to scroll right column always when it end?
For example, if I scrolled to end of page (or more than 200% height) and start to scroll up - I want to scroll to the right column too.

**Example:**
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/kitin/pen/poLQBRJ)

Answer (score 0):

**The common methods to disable scrolling in Javascript are:**

1. Force scroll the user back to a specific spot or element
   `window.onscroll = () => { window.scroll(0, 0); };`
2. Hide the overflow (no scrollbars)
   `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";`
3. Show the content in a fixed full-screen container
   `<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; position: fixed; top: 0; left:0; z-index: 999"></div>`